# VBA function: Compile Error: Argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7, vba6

```
Sub Test_Run()

MkDir "C:\ST\temp\AM"

End Sub
```

I am trying to create a new folder (AM) in an already existing directory which is C:\ST\temp. But it's causing error showing message: Argument not optional

Comment: Put the caret on the word `MkDir` and press Shift+F2. Where does that bring you?

Comment: After putting caret on MkDir and pressing shift+F2 key, it got redirected to a different  module query in same workbook. That query code is as follows:                             
Function MkDir(strDir As String, strPath As String)

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim path As String

path = strPath & strDir

If Not FSO.FolderExists(path) Then

          FSO.CreateFolder path

End If

End Function

Comment: So you have defined your own `MkDir` function (as opposed to the [built-in `MkDir` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement)) that accepts two parameters. You are supplying one.

Comment: That makes sense, it was actually a part of complicated created by someone else, so didn't notice that they already defined it as another function. Thanks alot for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your MkDir function is expecting two arguments and you are only sending one.

Instead of calling

MkDir "C:\ST\temp\AM"

Change it to:

MkDir "C:\ST\temp", "AM"

and it should work.

```
Function MkDir(strDir As String, strPath As String) 
   Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject 
   Dim path As String 

   path = strPath & strDir 
   If Not FSO.FolderExists(path) Then 
      FSO.CreateFolder path 
   End If 
End Function
```